When and why E_OS_LIMIT happn?
Code stop on errorhook accidenttally( CurrentError is A5 04 04 )
(E_OS_LIMIT,caused by default_init_task)
I check the default_init_task is basictask,autostart and task activation is 1.
Does E_OS_LIMIT mean too many tasks being activited or one task being activited too many times?
